# does not follow to Route by the Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm new to the study of React. 
By clicking on the link it appears in the address bar, but the component does not apply only if I refresh the page

index.js/

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
            <Router>
                <App/>
            </Router>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js/

```
class App extends Component {
render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <h4>Navigation</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/register">Registration</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={HomeContainer} />
                    <Route path="/register" component={Registration} />
                    <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

**Thankful in advance for your help**

Comment: You have defined `<Router>` twice. So better remove it from index.js, and their is no defined path for `/home` in `App.js`. add `<Route exact path="/home" component={HomeContainer} />` try hope it works.

Comment: My thanks. Its works